# What does ASLR(address space layout randomiztion) do?

Tags: security, linux-kernel, operating-system

I read that it is a security measure to protect against common attacks. The idea is that it keeps randomizing the virtual memory space which I believe will require periodic updates to the page table and the TLB? Am I correct?

My other question is, does it, at all, randomize the physical location of pages in the physical memory? Because I have been looking into the behavior of the physical memory under and without ASLR and the behavior is different.

Comment: The layout of pages in physical memory is pretty much always unpredictable (regardless of whether ALSR is enabled) for operating systems like Linux that heavily use virtual memory.

Answer (score 3):

ASLR is a security feature that's supposed to randomise the virtual address space of a program on *each run*. It doesn't hot-swap the virtual address space of a program *while* it's running (that would be a disaster).

The operating system will usually have to make periodic updates to the page table simply as part of scheduling. Whether ASLR is enabled is largely irrelevant to page table updates.

As to your other question, the layout of physical memory is essentially random whether you have ASLR enabled or not under Linux. Pages get swapped in and out of memory very often and, furthermore, the physical memory layout can quickly become fragmented. The only semi-predictable parts of physical memory would probably be memory reserved for DMA.

I'm still unsure how you managed to "look into the behaviour of physical memory" and conclude that the behaviour is significantly different between ASLR enabled and not.

Comment: Presumably, without ASLR physical memory is only incidentally random, and in simple cases with low uptime may be rather predictable - perhaps preserving internal order within the first large allocation until fragmentation is achieved. With ASLR it will hopefull be as unpredictable as virtual memory. Hardware debug tools may see physical memory, or presumably the kernel itself can dump mappings, at least when built for study.

Comment: I see your point and that's what I originally thought about but I don't believe Linux implements what you described on physical memory (at least a quick Google doesn't turn up with anything). It would probably be outside of the scope of what ASLR is hoping to defend against anyway.

Comment: I was basically looking into how the contents of pages change in the physical memory. In an idle operating system with ASLR enabled, many pages change completely (the whole 4 KB change) whereas if ASLR is disabled, the same idle OS will result in a pretty much stable physical memory. I used qemu to dump the physical memory FYI

Comment: @keeto It could be just incidental randomness. I'm not aware of any kernel function that deliberately randomizes the layout of physical memory.